# Finding end tag content in HTML with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm working with BeautifulSoup in Python34 on Windows 7 machine.
I have the following that i'm trying to parse

```
<bound method Tag.find of <div class="accordion">
<p> <span style="color:039; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold">Acetohydroxamic Acid (Lithostat) Tablets</span><br/><br/>



  <strong>Status: Currently in Shortage </strong><br/><br/>



         » <strong>Date first posted</strong>: 

        07/15/2014<br/>



 » <strong>Therapeutic Categories</strong>: Renal<br/>
</p><p style="padding:10px;">
</p>
<h3>

    Mission Pharmacal  (<em>Reverified  01/21/2015</em>)
```

I'm trying to get the "07/15/2014" out of the  line after Date first posted. I'm going to have to get the "Renal" out as well. I can find all the "strongs" using the .findAll("strong"), but I can't figure out a way to get something after the /strong>:  and before the next 
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [**`.next_sibling`**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) to get elements after `strong`
`isinstance(el, bs4.Tag)` to filter element that are not `Tag` and finally `re.sub` to strip blank line and `:`

```
In [38]: import re

In [39]: import bs4

In [40]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [41]: soup = BeautifulSoup("""<bound method Tag.find of <div class="accordion">   ....: <p> <span style="color:039; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold">Acetohydroxamic Acid (Lithostat) Tablets</span><br/><br/>
   ....: 
   ....: 
   ....: 
   ....:   <strong>Status: Currently in Shortage </strong><br/><br/>
   ....: 
   ....: 
   ....: 
   ....:         » <strong>Date first posted</strong>: 
   ....: 
   ....:                07/15/2014<br/>
   ....: 
   ....:     
   ....: 
   ....:  » <strong>Therapeutic Categories</strong>: Renal<br/>
   ....: </p><p style="padding:10px;">
   ....: </p>
   ....: <h3>
   ....: 
   ....:        Mission Pharmacal  (<em>Reverified  01/21/2015</em>)""")

In [42]: for strong_tag in soup.find_all('strong'):
   ....:     if not isinstance(strong_tag.next_sibling, bs4.Tag):
   ....:         print(re.sub(r'[:\s]+', '', strong_tag.next_sibling))
   ....:         
07/15/2014
Renal
```

**EDIT**

> Is there a way to get that date without using a loop?

Yes you can using the [**`text`**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument) argument to `find`.

```
re.sub('[:\s+]', '', soup.find('strong', text=re.compile('Date')).next_sibling)
```

Comment: That works great. I'm trying to explore the document using IDLE shell and learn BeuatifulSoup, specifically .next_sibling and the usage of "Tag" above. Is there a way to get that date without using a loop?

Comment: I'm still trying to get my head around the soup.find with the next_sibling. I'm trying to now get the "Mission Pharmacal " out into a string and get the text between the <em> tags. soup.find("h3") gives me the entire string with the tags so I tried re.sub('em','',soup.find("h3")) and it tells me there's a type error - expected string or buffer.  I appear to be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the regex `(?<=/strong>:)([^<]+)`. The `?<=` in the first group means that it is as positive lookbehind: this means "look for this string but don't capture it." And the second group means "match any character except for `<`. Finally the `strip` removes any extra whitespace around your group.

```
import re
import requests
s = requests.get(url).text
matches = [l.strip() for l in re.findall('(?<=/strong>:)([^<]+)',s)]
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit? I'm new to python - I dont quite get the syntax of the findall...